# java regex replace any double letter in word with single

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been searching for hours but can't find an answer, I apologize if this has been answered before.

I'm trying to check each word in a message for any double letters and remove the extra letter, words like wall or doll for example would become wal or dol. the purpose is for a fake language translation for a game, so far I've gottan as far as identifying the double letters but don't know how to replace them.

here's my code so far:

```
public String[] removeDouble(String[] words){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(words[i]);
        if (matcher.find()){
            words[i].replaceAll("what to replace with?");
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the whole replacement operation in one statement if you use back references:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1");
```

Note that you must assign the value returned from string methods that (appear to) change strings, because they return new strings rather than mutate the string.

Comment: Yes, `$1` is a back reference to the captured group `(.)`, and the match pattern also uses a back reference `\1` to the same group, which in English means "any character followed by the same character"

Comment: does this replace all occurences of any double letters or just the first occurence?

Comment: @BrandenPatey it replaces all occurrences. To replace only the first, use a negative look ahead `replaceAll("(.)\\1(?!.*(.)\\2)", "$1")` which asserts that no doubles are found in the input following the match

Answer (score 2):

[`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) does not modify the string in-place. (Java String is immutable) You need assign the returned value back.

And the `String.replaceAll` accepts two parameters.

Replace following line:

```
words[i].replaceAll("what to replace with?");
```

with:

```
words[i] = "what to replace with?";
```

Comment: this helped in other places in my code I was working on thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @BrandenPatey, I recommend Bohemian's way: `words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("(.)\\1", "what to replace with?");`

Comment: yeah went with that, but I hadn't thought to assign the replacement to the words[i] var